# Nested radical sequence convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, nested-radicals

How do I prove the sequence $\{\sqrt{7}, \sqrt{7\sqrt{7}},\sqrt{7\sqrt{7\sqrt{7}}}{,... \}}$ converges at 7?  I understand intuitively that the final term would be $7^{1/2} \cdot7^{1/4} \cdot7^{1/8}\ldots$ , and that would converge ultimately to $7^1$ but I'm not sure how to properly show that.  Thanks!

Comment: The $n$-th term of the sequence is $7^{\sum_{k=1}^n2^{-k}}.$ Now use the fact that $\sum_{k=1}^n2^{-k}$ is a geometric series to conclude that your sequence converges to $7.$

Answer (score 1):

use the geometric series 
$${\frac {1}{1-x}}=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }x^{n}\quad {\text{ for }}|x|<1\!$$
$$\{\sqrt{7\sqrt{7\sqrt{7}}}{... \}}=7^{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+...}=7^{\frac{1}{2}(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+...)}=7^{\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2}}}=7^1$$

Answer (score 0):

$$a_1 = \sqrt{7}$$
$$0<a_1 < 7$$
$$a_{n+1} = \sqrt{7a_{n}}$$
By geometric mean,
$$a_{n} < a_{n+1} < 7$$

Hence, $a_{n}$ is monotonic increasing and bounded above

$$\sqrt{7} \le a_{n} < a_{n+1} < 7$$
$$7-a_{n+1}=\frac{\sqrt{7}(7-a_{n})}{\sqrt{7}+\sqrt{a_{n}}}$$
$$0<7-a_{n+1} \le \frac{\sqrt{7}(7-a_{n})}{\sqrt{7}+\sqrt{a_{1}}}$$
$$0<7-a_{n+1} \le
\left( \frac{\sqrt{7}}{\sqrt{7}+\sqrt[4]{7}} \right)^n (7-a_{1})$$
Since $0<\dfrac{\sqrt{7}}{\sqrt{7}+\sqrt[4]{7}}<1$,

$$7-a_{n+1} \to 0 \quad \text{as} \quad n\to \infty$$